# Touch device button click not working in Bootstrap col-class element

Tags: android, html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, touch

I came across a strange problem in my Bootstrap/Angular application.

I have a button that did not work on my Android phone (an probably other touch devices as well), but worked fine on my desktop. The HTML for the button is:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="start()">Start</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

After trying a lot of different things, I figured out that if I removed "col-xs-12" class from the parent div it worked. So this works:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="start()">Start</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is of course not a solutions as I still intend to use Bootstrap in the application.

I also tried using the ngTouch module from Angular, but it doesn't make any difference. I don't think that Angular is the problem as a simple javascript `onclick="alert('Click')"` doesn't work either.

Does anyone know why this is happening or what I can do to solve it properly?

**EDIT**

Question closed - a custom Angular directive on the page caused this.

Comment: could you provide a jsfiddle or plunker? will make things easier to solve

Comment: I just created a fiddle, but it did not show the problem. I guess something else in my application together with the bootstrap class is causing the problem. I'll keep looking.

Answer (score 0):

Try using touch events so that it works both on android and web view

```
<div ng-controller="demoCtrl">

<div>
<div class='btn' on-touch="clickedOrTouched(4)">Touch or click me</div>
    <div class='btn' on-touch="clickedOrTouched">Touch or click me</div>
        <div class='btn' on-touch="clickedOrTouched">Touch or click me</div>
</div>
<hr>
<div>{{messages.join(' | ')}}</div>
```

javascript code:

```
var app = angular.module('test', []);
app.directive('onTouch', function() {
return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function(scope, elm, attrs) {
        var ontouchFn = scope.$eval(attrs.onTouch);
        elm.bind('touchend', function(evt) {
            scope.$apply(function() {
                ontouchFn.call(scope, evt.which);
            });
        });
        elm.bind('click', function(evt){
                scope.$apply(function() {
                    ontouchFn.call(scope, evt.which);
                });
        });
    }
};
```

});

```
app.controller('demoCtrl', function($scope) {
$scope.messages = [];
$scope.clickedOrTouched = function(item) {
    (item) ? item = 1 : null
        for (var i =0 ; i< item ; i++) {
    $scope.messages.push("Fire");
}
};
```

});

btn style:

```
.btn {
display: block;
border: 1px solid;
height: 100px;
width: 100px;
float: left;
margin: 20px;
padding: 10px;
```

}

Try this example.Here touchevent works on mobile and click on web view.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Although this a smart way to create a button that reacts on touch, that was not my problem. I was trying to figure out _why_ my button did not work, and not a different way to create a button. Sorry if I wasn't clear about that.

Comment: I just added this code and it clicked on all my buttons on the screen. And deleting all my objects in the database... At least I found a bug